# Half a spoonful?

Tags: phrase-usage

This kind of measurement doesn't appear by googling, let's say you are a diabetic and ice cream can also be a high source of sugar, which is bad to your health. Moreover, you insist and say:

> Oh, I'll just have **half a spoonful.**
>   <sub>(excerpted from a book ''The 4 hour workweek'')</sub>

Are the bold letters correct as for a unit of measurement?

Comment: Why not? If you can have a quantity, whatever it is called, why couldn't you have half of it?

Comment: @Robusto - I'm guessing this is a question about "half a spoonful" vs. "a half spoonful," but, if I'm right about that, the OP should really clarify.

Comment: I'm guessing the question is about the contrast between "half" and "full". Compare this to "five o'clock" and "five thirty" (not *"five thirty o'clock").

Comment: @laugh, sry but it's not, there are no ''contrasting conjunctions'' written in the highlighted question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Talking causually - yes, it's fine.**

As you can have *a spoonful*, it is also possible to have *half a spoonful*, or *a half spoonful*.

However, it is important to note that these are very imprecise measurements, and many people will not take you literally when you say that. Instead, it will generally imply that you can only eat a very small amount of the ice-cream.

*This is similar to when somebody says they'll have "just a french fry", but may actually take two or three.*

---

For more precise measurements such as recipes, the exact type of spoon should be used and sometimes with the modifier "heaped":

> Tablespoon, tbsp. e.g. 1/2 tbsp is half a tablespoon
>
> Teaspoon, tsp. e.g. 1/2 tsp is half a teaspoon
>
> Heaped tablespoon. e.g. 1 heaped tbsp, which is a tablespoon holding so much there is a little heap on top (as opposed to it being measured flat, up to the rim).

*As pointed out in comments, Heaped may also be referred to as Heaping or Rounded, depending on the author.*

Comment: **heaped** or  **heaping**.

Comment: "Scant" is the opposite of "heaping" - it means slightly less than.